# Tridion 2011/2013 support for CP metadata?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

In my current project we still use R53 :-(, and we would like to be able to add metadata to component presentations dynamically at publish time, and then use this information in Broker queries. This seems not possible in R53, but since we will be migrating to 2011 in the near future I was wondering if this functionality will become available then?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no Metadata for ComponentPresentations stored in Broker in 2011 or 2013 versions. This functionality has never been implemented on Content Delivery side. You can however build your own deployer/storage extension to pick-up on the RenderMetadata, to store it and to make is query-able.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the TOM? Then you can call TCMScriptAssistant.AddMetadata

On TOM.NET, it's RenderedItem.AddMetadata

Comment: I don't think the Metadata added by 'RenderedItem.AddMetadata' ends up in the Broker Database. See this post from Mihai: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/10/rendereditem-metadata-and-instruction.html

Comment: Thanks Albert. That's a disappointment, because as I recall the TOM method worked exactly as you'd have expected, at least back in 5.3. I just checked out the documentation, and the two methods are described identically, so one must assume that the intention was for the RenderedItem version to be a replacement for the other. Despite Mihai's willingness to work around this, I'd say it's a bug. (Unless someone wants to persuade me otherwise.)